# Extending 60 days Facebook token

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm using Hybridauth to connect with Facebook. Everything works well at that point ;-)

I get a token and when I check it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ I see it has 2 months expiration.

After some days, for example, 50 days, I see the token will expire in 10 days indeed.

I try to extend with method documented (and described in other StackOverflow questions) with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Then I receive ANOTHER token, but if I check that new token in the "tools debug" page, it returns the same expiration time (10 days in the example) ... and indeed, in 10 days, the old token and this new one are expired.

Then ... how can I get a working extended token ?

**EDIT TO ASK SPECIFIC QUESTION**

In my case, users connects their facebook to their accounts and then I can get **each day** new photos from their timelines, and obviously I don't want them to connect (or click any button) each 60 days to renew this. I guess this can be automated forever (since there's no more offline_access permission) as other websites do.

How can let a user to connect their FB account to my site, and then I have a way to grab new content in his timeline *forever* ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to redirect to user to the login dialog url again, as described in  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#expiredtokens

> If the access token becomes invalid, the solution is to have the person log in again, at which point you will be able to make API calls on their behalf once more. The login flow your app uses for new people should determine which method you need to adopt.

Normally there should be no user action required when redirecting, if you don't request more permissions.

Comment: I can't use that solution... once the user connects his Facebook account, it's a night "cron" process who takes stuff from his timeline ... there's no more "user interaction" with website ... it has to be other solution since many sites allows you to connect with Facebook and although you take more than 2 months to come back, the connection (and grab of data) is alive forever.

Comment: No, that's not true.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#termtokens `...long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about 60 days...`

Comment: Ok, so as I said, there must be a way to "play" with user's timeline (Open Graph requests) without asking them to "click" in any site each 60 days!

Comment: Just ONE example: Endomondo, I connected with my Facebook. I haven't get inside their application for 6 months, and they STILL CAN post in my timeline and after going to website, I HAD NOT to login again.

Comment: Well, if you say so. Good luck finding a solution with the current Graph API version.

Comment: Endomondo uses the JS SDK to update your session so if you're still logged into Facebook when you go to their site they'll get a new token with no interaction needed