# Why does a new FB long-lived access token expire at the same time as the previous one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a small misunderstanding with how FB access token is being refreshed.

I'm using FB JS SDK and every time I visit my page (as well as when I relogin) I get a new short-lived access token.
Then I send it to the server side and exchange it to a long-lived access token.

But despite I get a new long-lived access token, it still expires at the same time as the previous long-lived token. [Facebook Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) says that token, I've just got, was issued 18 hours ago.

Is this a normal behavior? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like FB refreshes an expiration time of a new long-lived access token if user visits a page ***in one day*** after the initial long-lived access token is issued. In this case you can get a short-lived access token and exchange it for a long-lived token, which would have a new expiration time (i.e. 60 days).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question:

- [Extending 60 days Facebook token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835454/extending-60-days-facebook-token/27837131#27837131)

Basically, you can't refresh a long-lived token before it expires.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a true :) If user visits my page in 24 hours, the new long-lived token (which I get by exchanging for short-lived token) has a new expiration time